# http4s json handling in authed routes

Tags: scala, scala-cats, circe, http4s

I am using `Scala 3` and `http4s 1.0.0-M35`. I want to use auth with json handling.

```
val routes = AuthedRoutes.of[User, IO] {
case request@POST -> Root / "dialog" / LongVar(dialogId) / "send" as user => {
      for {
        sendMessageRequest <- request.as[SendMessageRequest]
```

But got error

```
[error]    |        sendMessageRequest <- request.as[SendMessageRequest]
[error]    |                              ^^^^^^^^^^
[error]    |value as is not a member of org.http4s.ContextRequest[cats.effect.IO, repository.User], but could be made available as an extension method.
```

It suggests some imports:

```
[error]    |One of the following imports might fix the problem:
[error]    |
[error]    |  import cats.Functor.nonInheritedOps.toFunctorOps
[error]    |  import cats.Functor.ops.toAllFunctorOps
[error]    |  import cats.NonEmptyTraverse.ops.toAllNonEmptyTraverseOps
[error]    |  import cats.Traverse.ops.toAllTraverseOps
[error]    |  import cats.implicits.toFunctorOps
[error]    |  import cats.syntax.all.toFunctorOps
[error]    |  import cats.syntax.functor.toFunctorOps
```

But after importing it, I have another error:

`sendMessageRequest` type is `org.http4s.ContextRequest[cats.effect.IO, service.CreateDialogRequest]`

How to use json handling in AuthedRoutes it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem. Just:

```
request.req.as
```